# Blazor LocationChanged stops navigation?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a page which takes two url parameters:

```html
@page "document/{partition}/{id}"
```

If I type in a url of say, `https://somehost:1234/document/abcd/xyz123` the page loads fine.

I have registered a `LocationChanged` event which does some stuff:

```cs
private async void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
{
     await DoStuff();
}
```

The issue I have is if I have an anchor tag link with a `href="/document/klmn/defg9876"` and click the link, my event fires but my browser doe not navigate and load the new document. If I add `NavigateTo(e.Location)` to my event handler I get an endless loop.

How do I get Blazor to navigate onward to the url after processing my event?

**EDIT**

If I add a link back to the home page then I can go from `document` page to `home` page. Between two `document` links the url in the browser changes but `OnInitialized` doesn't run for the new url. I'm obviously page lifecycle challenged.

Answer (score 0):

OK it was an issue of my understanding the page lifecycle.

I was assuming that `OnInitialized()` would be called each time my url parameters changed but I instead have to override the `OnParametersSetAsync()` method when the new `patition` and `document` parameters are available and then load my new document.